# save d3.map() to be able to restore it later

Tags: node.js, serialization, d3.js

I am creating a picture using d3, the picture is composed from node and link (arrow):

```
var graph = { nodes: d3.map(), edges: d3.map() };
```

Is there way to save nodes and edges using node.js to be able to restore it later?

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11759917/howt-to-serialize-object-in-javascript) may help.

Comment: Thanks. Maybe the best solution is save the properties of the node and of the links in a json object and when requested add nodes/links again.

Comment: You can save the actual objects.