# Converting JSON schema into a CQL (Cassandra) schema

Tags: node.js, cassandra, datastax, cql, jsonschema

I would like to convert a JSON object, like the one below, into a Cassandra schema/ table.

So for example, something like this:

```
{
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "name": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "age": {
            "type": "integer"
        }
    }
}
```

To something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS people (
    name text PRIMARY KEY,
    age int);
```

In Node.js, using the [Datastax Cassandra driver](https://github.com/datastax/nodejs-driver).

So essentially: using Node.js I would like to create Cassandra tables based on JSON schemas (without having to manually create the tables, but have Node parse the JSON object and build the script for creating the Cassandra table).

Comment: You can create entities for your data and then deserialize json to those entities. Take a look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11759917/how-to-serialize-an-object-in-javascript and https://www.npmjs.com/package/json-serialize.